# Where can I post a guide about how to set up a Raspberry Pi 3 for monero?

Tags: discussion

I just registered here, because I want to tell people how to install latest release on a RPI 3. Any suggestion where I can post a guide?

Comment: You can ask how to install Monero on a Raspberry Pi 3 here on Stack Exchange and answer your own question!

Comment: You can also submit a pull request to add a guide to this page: https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/user-guides/

Answer (score 3):

You should ask a question on regular Monero SE for how to set up a RPi3 for monero, and then answer your own question with a detailed how-to (as Jun Li recommended in the comment).

Answer (score 1):

There are build instructions on the Monero GitHub main page: https://github.com/monero-project/monero

My advice would be to edit that README.md if the instructions aren't correct.

If you mean how to just use the binaries, that's no different than for any brand of Linux, so probably shouldn't have it's own post.

Comment: I used to install it via the github guide, but it is not working (anymore?) I have the Raspberry 3, tried with the newest version of Raspbian, but u just can't compile it...to many errors. I decided to use Arch Linux and it worked almost instantly..

Comment: There is just one last problem. I store the blockchain on a external hdd and it works well if I start monerod manualy with the specific boot flags. But I want to it to autostart after boot/reboot...this is not working yet...any suggestions? maybe new question thread?